# Opera: Filter facebook from the web

Tags: opera, facebook, web-filtering

I'm a massive fan of the Opera browser, and dislike Facebook with a passion.  Are there any tools for Opera which can get rid of Facebook from my web browsing experience?  This includes any pages, link in, likes, etc. Checked for available extensions, but nothing as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use the **Facebook Blocker** extension: http://webgraph.com/resources/facebookblocker/
Opera.com extensions page: https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/facebook-blocker-2/

From the [Facebook Blocker website](http://webgraph.com/resources/facebookblocker/):

> **How did we get here?**
>
> We’re beginning to feel overwhelmed by
>   the frequency with which Facebook
>   links are starting to appear on many
>   of the sites we visit in our daily
>   routines, so we decided to do
>   something about it.
>
> **What does it do?**
>
> This browser extension stops Facebook
>   social plugins—including those within
>   iFrames—from running on sites other
>   than Facebook itself. This includes
>   ‘Like’ buttons, ‘Recommended’ lists,
>   and should also stop any Facebook
>   scripts from tracking your browsing
>   history.

Edit: Another extension, **[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/)** (which is what I now use, instead of Facebook Blocker), can also block Facebook-related content (among other trackers).

For Facebook Blocker and Ghostery, you could also contact the extension authors to report a non-blocked Facebook object on a website you visit.

[Facebook Blocker issue report page](https://github.com/alexrubin/Facebook-Blocker/issues); [Twitter](https://twitter.com/facebookblocker)
[Ghostery support page](https://getsatisfaction.com/ghostery)

Comment: Brilliant, I love the way it blocks "iLike" links, that's what I was principally after.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need extensions for blocking Facebook, you should be able to block it with the built-in **Content Blocker**.

Go to: `Settings -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Content -> Blocked Content...` and there add `*://*.facebook.com/*`

This blocks any FB icons delivered from the Facebook static network (`s-static.ak.facebook.com`), as well as the main scripts which you see pop-up on sites which use Facebook Widgets and API (`connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`).

If you want even better protection, try this **extension** on top of the above:
https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/external-scripts/

It's essentially NoScript for Opera, so unless you put Facebook to the whitelist, nothing should get through.